# Why do I get NoMethodError in Games#new for my game form but the analog for my Users#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I am creating a a site in RoR and and I have built the user signup and login forms. Everything works great. The thing is, I went to create another object called games, which functions almost identically to users, but when I try to interact with it I get an error. I built the forms almost exactly the same and the routing I congruent.

Here is my user new.html.erb:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
    <h1 class="heading1" >Sign up</h1>
    <br>
      <div>
        <%= form_for(@user, :html => { :class => 'form' }) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <br>
           <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <br>
          <%= f.label :username %>
          <%= f.text_field :username %>
        <br>
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <%= f.password_field :password %>
        <br>
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
        <br>
    <br>
          <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "submit" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and my users controller new and create methods:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
def new
 @user =User.new
end
  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :username, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

and my game new.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 class="heading1" >Create Game</h1>
<br>
  <div>
    <%= form_for(@game, :html => { :class => 'form' }) do |i| %>
      <%= i.label :title %>
      <%= i.text_field :title %>
    <br>
    <br>
      <%= i.submit "Create Game", class: "submit" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my game controller:

```
    def create
        @game = Game.new(game_params)
        if @game.save
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'create'
        end
    end

    def new
        @game = Game.new
    end

    private

    def game_params
        params.require(:game).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

and my routing file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
 resources :users
  match '/new_game',  to: 'games#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#home'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

The rails server error page reads:

```
NoMethodError in Games#new
Showing /Users/Karen/Desktop/BR2/app/views/games/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `games_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbfd6bdb260>:0x007fbfd6bd8948>
Extracted source (around line #7):
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

  <h1 class="heading1" >Create Game</h1>
  <br>
    <div>
      <%= form_for(@game, :html => { :class => 'form' }) do |i| %>
        <%= i.label :title %>
        <%= i.text_field :title %>
    <br>

Rails.root: /Users/Karen/Desktop/BR2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/games/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_games_new_html_erb___3427370169918602482_70230959128880'
Request

Parameters:

None
```

I really appreciate all and any help. if there is any more information I can provide please say so.

Thank you

Comment: The standard first step after rout helper errors is  rake routes to see what helpers you really get from your route config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that when you do `bundle exec rake routes` in your console, you have not actually created named routes for your games paths.

If you're using `match` and you want to name a route (so you have something like `games_path` available), you'd have to do this:

```
match `/games`, as: 'games', to: 'games#index', via: :get
```

A much easier way is to use resources for most of your routes, and just go with the default RESTFUL paths:

```
resources :games

# Now you have access to '/games/new', '/games/:id',
# '/games', etc, as well as names such as `games_path`.
# Check `bundle exec rake routes` for all of them.
```

See [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information

---

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like an idiot. I guess I just forgot to declare it as a resource. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you found it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to add `games` specific RESTful routes in `routes.rb`

```
resources :games
```

and remove `match '/new_game',  to: 'games#new',            via: 'get'` route.

Doing this will give you the following Restful routes:

```
Prefix        Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
games         GET    /games(.:format)                     games#index
              POST   /games(.:format)                     games#create
new_game      GET    /games/new(.:format)                 games#new
edit_game     GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)            games#edit
game          GET    /games/:id(.:format)                 games#show
              PATCH  /games/:id(.:format)                 games#update
              PUT    /games/:id(.:format)                 games#update
              DELETE /games/:id(.:format)                 games#destroy
```

So upon form submission your application would route to `create` action (`games_path`) by *HTTP Post request*.

Currently you have just defined a *single route* for `games` resource which routes to `new` action with

```
match '/new_game',  to: 'games#new',            via: 'get'
```

But there is **no route for `create` action** which is why you receive the error as `undefined method 'games_path'` on the form

If you don't wish to use the RESTful routes(`resources :games`) then you would have to define a route as:

```
match '/games', as: 'games', to: 'games#create', via: 'post'
```

for `create` action.